# Primitive of $(e^x+e^{2x})^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am looking for a primitive of $\frac{1}{e^{x}+e^{2x}}$. I there an easy way to find it? Thanks.

Comment: Let $x = \ln t$.

Comment: it is not a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{1}{e^{x}+e^{2x}} dx=\int\frac{1}{e^{x}(1+e^{x})} dx$$

u-sub:
$$u=e^x$$
$$du=e^x\; dx$$

Well...
$$du=e^x\; dx\rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{u}$$

Use the u:
$$\int\frac{1}{e^{x}(1+e^{x})} dx=\int\frac{1}{u^2(1+u)} du$$

Partial fractions:

$$\int\frac{1}{u^2(1+u)} du=\int \left(\frac1{u^2}+\frac1{u+1}-\frac1{u} \right)\;du$$

Now it should be easy to integrate. Answer is $$\ln|e^{-x}+1|-e^{-x}$$

Comment: Thanks Shahar, It is exactly the type of solutions if was searching for, I found exactly the same steps but I stopped at the "Partial fraction" step